# How to find the distance and the rotation from camera to object/marker using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, position

I have done some 6D Pose estimation, and have the Oriented Bounding Box (OBB) of the detected object. So, now I would like to know the ground truth and get the error of the estimated orientation and the position. The detected object is a rectangular box as shown in the image.
[image: Object with the marker]

How can I know the distance and the rotation of a marker (black box over the red one) to the camera? The red box in the image is the object and the black one is the estimated 6DPose.

So would like to do image postprocessing to get the error of the position and the orientation. So, how can get the error from this image, knowing the real dimensions of the box, camera parameters, and the distance from the camera to the object? So the triangulation formula can give me the distance but then how to get the orientation?

Would be OpenCV to look after?
Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the marker correspondings and [solvePnp](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=solvepnp#solvepnp) is what you are looking for

Comment: Marker correspondings are the lines or corners of the marker? How to find the marker correspondings? Sorry, Im new to this. Would appreciate a help

Comment: I was not using OpenCV. To get the marker I was using Point Cloud Library (PCL) and PCA

Comment: it depends, mostly corners, try sift, orb like feature detect and matching methods. I guess pcl might not have this "out of box" implementations

Comment: So I have to do image postprocessing? so marker corresponding to the object image, correct? And then use solvePnP? So one image is the marker and another one is the object and find the 2D point correspondings between two images? And then apply solvePnP? Is that the way?

Comment: https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/AugmentedRealityWithArucoMarkers yes, good thing to read

Comment: I saw aruco marker. But I need some quick results. So as said in one image is my visualization marker and in other is the image with the object(the red box) . Correct? Just need to find the correspondings using mostly corners,  sift, orb like feature detect and matching methods, and then apply solvePnP. Right?